# Right way of passing consistent data from DB to user without repeatedly querying

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, middleware

Database stores some data about the user which *almost* never change. Well sometimes information might change if the user wants to edit his name for example.

Data information is about each user's name, username and his company data.

The first two are being shown to his navigation bar all the time using `ejs`, like `User_1 is logged in`, his company profile data when he needs to create an invoice.

My current way is to fetch user data through middleware using `router.use` so the extracted information is always available through all routes/views, for example:

```
router.use(function(req, res ,next) { // this block of code is called as middleware in every route

    req.getConnection(function(err,conn){      
      uid = req.user.id;

       if(err){
          console.log(err);
          return next("Mysql error, check your query");
        }

        var query = conn.query('SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE uid = ? ', uid, function(err,rows){

          if(err){
              console.log(err);
              return next(err, uid, "Mysql error, check your query");
          }

          var userData = rows;

          return next();
       });
    });
})
```

.

I understand that this is not an optimal way of passing user profile data to every route/view since it makes new DB queries every time the user navigates through the application.

What would be a better way of having this data available without repeating the same query in each route **yet** having them re-fetched once the user changes a portion of this data, like his fullname ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just stumbled into the world of "caching", welcome! Caching is a very popular choice for use cases like this, as well as many others. A cache is essentially somewhere to store data that you can get back much quicker than making a full DB query, or a file read, etc.

Before we go any further, it's worth considering your use case. If you're serving only a few users and have a low load on your service, caching might be over-engineering and in fact making a DB request might be the simplest idea. Adding caching can add a lot of complexity to your code as things move forward, not enough to scare you, but enough to cause hard to trace bugs. So consider for a moment your service load, if it's not very high (say an internal application for somewhere you work with only maybe a few requests every few minutes) then just reading from the DB is probably not going to slow down a request too much. In this case, reading from the DB is the simplest and probably best solution. However, if you're noticing that this DB request is slowing down your application for requests or making it harder to scale up, then caching might be for you.

A really popular approach for this would be to get something like "redis" which is a key-value database that holds everything in memory (RAM). Redis can sit as a service like MySQL and has a very basic query language. It is blindingly fast and can scale to enormous loads. If you're using Express, there are a number of NPM modules that help you access a redis instance. Simply push in your credentials and you can then make GET and SET requests (to get data or to set data).

In your example, you may wish to store a users profile in a JSON format against their user id or username in redis. Then, create a function called `getUserProfile` which takes in the ID or username. This can then look it up in redis, if it finds the record then it can return it to your main controller logic. If it does not, it can look it up in your MySQL database, save it in redis, and then return it to the controller logic (so it'll be able to get it from cache next time).

Your next problem is known for being a very pesky problem in computer science. It's "Cache Invalidation", in this case if your user profile updates you want to "invalidate" your cache. A way of doing this would be to update your cached version when the user updates their profile (or any other data saved). Alternatively, you could also just remove the cached version from redis and then next time it's requested from `getUserProfile`, it will be fetched from the DB fresh, and then put into redis for next time.

There are many other ways to approach this, but this will most likely solve your problem in the simplest way without too much overhead. It will also be easy to expand in the future!